# ThreadLocal in combination with IHttpModule

Tags: .net, thread-local-storage, ihttpmodule

I have been playing around in a webproject where I in a HttpModule would like to prepare some data the different classes on a later stage should work.

Would it be safe to expose that data in a public static accessable ThreadLocal storage?

ie.

```
public static ThreadLocal<A> storage = new ThreadLocal<A>();

private void Application_BeginRequest(Object source, EventArgs )
{
    storage.Value = new A();
}
```

My initial test shows that code executed in my controllers etc. actually works on the same thread as the above snippet from a module is executed in.

ie.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var o = module.storage;
    if (o.IsValueCreated)
    {
        // WORX
    }
    return View();
}
```

But I could not find any documentation that ensured me this is a guaranteed behaviour.

Would this work? Or should I get this behaviour in an other way?

(Needless to say that any threads that I spin up myself on a later state would loose connection to the TLS.)

Comment: I'm pretty sure there are no guarantees -- ASP.NET, including MVC, uses [thread-agility](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=asp.net+thread+agility) which doesn't play nicely with thread-local storage. Probably better to use [`HttpContext.Items`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.items.aspx) instead, if you can.

Comment: Got it. But then I could have

    public static A Current{
        get
        {
            return (A)HttpContext.Current.Items["a"];
        }
    }

Comment: You probably should check the samples first to learn how to use `ThreadLocal` first.

Comment: What makes you think that I do not know how to use ThreadLocal ? Question is actually more related to IIS threading model.

Is there a hint that I did not get here?